# convert mail to xml

Tags: .net, xml, email-client

I'm using a TCP IP .NET program to retrieve mails as text formated from a pop3 server.
I'd like to convert the messages I receive into XML.

Anybody knows of a email text message to XML file - with headers, from, to, subject, body and html body (no attachments though)?

Alternatively, I'd like to find a email XSD shema I could use...

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a library which can serialize and deserialize XML<->MIME, this becomes really simple. For instance, MailMessage class of MailBee.NET MIME can do this. The whole library is paid but mime functionality is free if used without POP3, IMAP, etc.

http://www.afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/mime-component

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a tutorial](http://www.roseindia.net/xml/xml_schema_example.shtml) for learning XSD; it happens to use email as an example. These sorts of examples are easy to find. I don't think there is a standard XSD for email, although there might be something I missed over at [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/standards/xml/)

Comment: Hi kelloti, Sorry I can't accept your answer but the sample given is far too simplistic and I doubt the given XML would resist a couple of HTML body enabled emails!... ANyway, good try :-). For the information of whom in interested, here is the XML snippet:

Comment: <E-mail>
<To>Rohan</To>
<From>Amit</From>
<Subject>Surprise....</Subject>
<Body>Be ready for a cruise...</Body>
</E-mail>

Comment: It would accept HTML fine if you namespaced the email elements. And how complex can an email be? Any attachments could be base64'd into `<attachment />` elements